# Is 'connected' appropriate for bamboo?

Tags: word-usage, word-in-context

Three pieces of bamboo are connected.

The bamboo is used to measure the height of roof.

Can the word "connected" be used for bamboo?

How if I use the word "to assemble"?

Comment: Why do you think it might not be appropriate?  It all depends on the context, which you haven't given us.

Comment: Could you please edit this to give context, as well as explain what is "bamboo subject"? Do you mean with bamboo as the subject?

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on *how* they are connected. If you are talking about pieces of bamboo that are tied together to make a longer piece – that is, something like this:

[image]

then you could say that the bamboo is **tied together end-to-end**.

Tied together (or **lashed together**) simply means the bamboo is put together, but there are several ways bamboo can be tied together, like this, for example:

[image]

However, if you specify *end-to-end*, that means that the end of one stick is tied to the end of another stick, which increases the total length.

If no rope is used, but the bamboo is cut so that one piece fits inside the other, you might be able to say they are *notched* together.

Answer (score 1):

The main part of the subject in your sentence is the word **pieces** and *of bamboo* is simply describing it. You could rephrase the subject to read:

> **Three bamboo pieces** are connected.

so this becomes more obvious. The verb you use refers to *pieces* and these can be connected, but also joined, attached, linked...

If you would like to refer to the technical details of how exactly they were attached - you could say glued (together) or taped (together) if you used glue or tape to connect them.

I wouldn't say that "assembled" is necessarily wrong, but it doesn't sound right to me, as it reminds me of a set that came in pieces and you need to assemble it (while I read your sentence as: I found some bamboo pieces lying around and I decided to attach three of those to one another). The definition of assemble that I have in mind in this context:

> [with object] Fit together the separate component parts of (a machine or other object): *my new machine is being assembled and my old one dismantled*

from [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/assemble)